# Docker ENV value from printf does not work

Tags: bash, docker, sed, dockerfile

My scenario is a little bit complex:

1. I have an environment variable in my `Dockerfile`, which is a path: `ENV ORACLE_HOME=/home/oracle`
2. I need to do some file manipulation later, so I am using sed
3. Unfortunately I need to escape the path characters `\` for sed before I use the variable.

**This is what I have:**

```
ENV ORACLE_HOME=/home/oracle
ENV ORACLE_HOME_ESCAPED="$(printf '%q\n' "$ORACLE_HOME")"
RUN sed 's/.*pattern.*/\"-Dsomekey='${ORACLE_HOME_ESCAPED}'\"/' file
```

The `RUN` line works fine if `ORACLE_HOME` only contains simple characters.
My escaping command with `printf` works properly in `bash`, but it does not work in `Dockerfie`.

Unfortunately, I only have `GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)` and there is no update for bash 4.4 so I am NOT able to use `${@Q}` notation. I use `oraclelinux:7-slim` as a base image.

Any suggestion about what is wrong with the `printf`?

Comment: Please post a fulll [MCVE]. `printf '%q` is for escaping _shell_ re-evaulation, not sed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any suggestion about what is wrong with the printf?

There's nothing wrong with printf, there is however a problem with how the variables is *used*.

No `ENV` does *not* run a shell that would expand `$(...)` - ENV is a simple `a=b` assignment with no expansions.

Try the following and note how quotes are used *when expanding* the variable, not assigning it:

```
FROM alpine
ENV ORACLE_HOME="not simple characters?!@#^**^&()"
RUN set -x && \
    printf "%s\n" a pattern b > file && \
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-a-sed-replace-pattern
    ORACLE_HOME_ESCAPED_FOR_SED=$(printf '%s\n' "$ORACLE_HOME" | sed -e 's/[\/&]/\\&/g') && \
    sed 's/.*pattern.*/"-Dsomekey='"$ORACLE_HOME_ESCAPED_FOR_SED"'"/' file
# these quotes                     ^                            ^
# prevent word splitting
```

Results in:

```
$ docker build .
...
Step 3/3 : RUN set -x &&     printf "%s\n" a pattern b > file &&     ORACLE_HOME_ESCAPED_FOR_SED=$(printf '%s\n' "$ORACLE_HOME" | sed -e 's/[\/&]/\\&/g') &&     sed 's/.*pattern.*/"-Dsomekey='"$ORACLE_HOME_ESCAPED_FOR_SED"'"/' file
 ---> Running in 9a98e726e145
+ printf '%s\n' a pattern b
+ printf '%s\n' 'not simple characters?!@#^**^&()'
+ sed -e 's/[\/&]/\\&/g'
+ ORACLE_HOME_ESCAPED_FOR_SED='not simple characters?!@#^**^\&()'
+ sed 's/.*pattern.*/"-Dsomekey=not simple characters?!@#^**^\&()"/' file
a
"-Dsomekey=not simple characters?!@#^**^&()"
b
Removing intermediate container 9a98e726e145
 ---> 9f9276112bf0
Successfully built 9f9276112bf0
```

> I need to do some file manipulation later, so I am using sed

Depends on the manipulation to be done - in templating cases, `envsubst` is just enough.

> I need to escape the path characters \ for sed before I use the variable.

Yes you do - alternatively use a different `s` delimiter - `s!something!somethingelse!`.